# PHP PayPal post parameters in the return URL

Tags: php, paypal

What is the quantity parameters for the return in Paypal. I have searched in google but I can't seem to find one. This is the examples that I found so far, but I need the quantity

```
$example1 = $_GET['amt']; //this for the ammount
$example2 = $_GET['cc'];  //this for the currency
$example3 = $_GET['tx'];  //this for the tax
```

Comment: have you looked up the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be this `auth_amount`, but you should read the documentation in depth...
[IPN and PDT variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/), hope it helps...